# How to use conditions in self association without joins?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, associations, cakephp-2.0

I have `Product` model [`id, parent_id, x`].
I want to append on each Product, single `ProductParent`, only when `Product.x = 0`, and `Product.parent_id = ProductParent.id`.

What i try is:

```
public $hasOne = array(
    'ProductParent' => array(
        'className' => 'Product',
        'foreignKey' => false,
        'conditions' => array(
            'ProductParent.id = Product.parent_id',
            'Product.x' => 0
        )
    )
);
```

And get output `Product.parent_id` is unknown.

Comment: `'foreignKey' => false,` why do that and then set a condition which is equivalent? Perhaps start with (and add to the question) the exact sql that gives you the data you want.

Comment: @AD7six i was also try 'foreignKey' => 'parent_id' and get the same result: Product.x is unknown

Comment: Please add the actual error message - and executed sql - to the question. Along with the corrected version which does do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Tree behavior. Check this: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/tree.html

Comment: I doubt this answer helps the OP